# How to modify the DACPAC model at build time?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I want to alter the table model during build time in my `BuildContributor`.  Here is some sample code:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Deployment;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Model;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    [ExportBuildContributor("MyNamespace.MyBuildContributor", "1.0.0.0")]
    public class MyBuildContributor : BuildContributor
    {
        protected override void OnExecute(BuildContributorContext context, IList<ExtensibilityError> messages)
        {
            foreach (var table in context.Model.GetObjects(DacQueryScopes.UserDefined, ModelSchema.Table))
            {
                var tableName = table.Name.Parts.Last();
                var rowId = "alter table " + tableName + " add rowid uniqueidentifier";
                context.Model.AddObjects(rowId);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The build succeeds with no errors but I don't see `rowid` in any of the tables when I go look in the `model.xml` file in `bin\Debug\MyDb.dacpac`.

Comment: Is your code being called? Shove in a MessageBox.Show or Debugger.Launch at the beginning of the OnExecute?

Comment: It is.  I added `Console.WriteLine`s which showed up in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Model.AddObjects in this context.

Model.AddObjects from (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.model.tsqlmodel.addobjects(v=sql.120).aspx#M:Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Model.TSqlModel.AddObjects(System.String)):

"Adds objects to the model based on the contents of a TSql Script string. The script should consist of valid TSql DDL statements. Objects added using this method cannot be updated or deleted at a later point as update/delete requires a script name to be specified when adding the objects. If this is a requirement use the AddOrUpdateObjects method instead."

I.E it can only add objects like tables or stored procedure, columns by themselves aren't added to the model.

If you want to update an existing object (i.e. to add a column to an existing table) you will need to use "TSqlModel.AddOrUpdateObjects" which also takes a script name. You can get the script name from a build contributor by using:

`var sourceName = table.GetSourceInformation().SourceName;`

Then you can build the updated script you want (just a rough outline of rebuilding the SQL for stack overflow, I'm sure you can do better):

```
var sql = table.GetScript();
sql = sql.Trim().TrimEnd(')', ';') + ", rowid uniqueidentifier);";

var sourceName = table.GetSourceInformation().SourceName;
model.AddOrUpdateObjects(sql, sourceName, new TSqlObjectOptions());
```

There are a few ways you could create your new script but basically what you need is a new script which has your extra column and the original table definition which you can pass to AddorUpdateObjects to overwrite the original create table statement.

If you don't get a source to use in AddorUpdateObjects then maybe you could use a post-deploy script to add it to any table you need and then use a deployment contributor to remove the drop column step.

You could also look at using a deployment contributor instead to add the new column step to that.

Hope it helps! Let me know how you get on :)

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work either.  I even hard-coded the new script just to test the concept.  The new column still isn't in the output DACPAC model.  (There was an error message during the first build which was **not** encountered in succeeding rebuilds: `The write operation failed. You must first acquire write access from DataSchemaModelController.`  Neither the first build nor the succeeding rebuilds produced the expected output.)

Comment: i've been going over the build contributor documentation (it didn't take very long!) and it seems to suggest you can't modify the contents and I also can't find a way to get a write lock on the model (it is all internal code) - so I think you will need to do something like read every object and create a new model in a new dacpac or wait until the build has finished and open and edit the model in the dacpac and save that - if you have a preference I should be able to knock up a quick demo

Comment: No, it's OK.  I was hoping there was a way to do it in-place through the `BuildContributor` extension.  Thanks for your time!

Comment: One more question, why do you want to add a column on the fly and not add it to the source code?

Comment: It's only one of two objects that I want to add automatically to the build.  The other is a trigger that saves the row state.  I want the team to be able to just specify in some config file a table is "journaled" and then the required objects will be added to the model by the `BuildContributor`.